# How to display specific data in year

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g

I had to return procedure which will display a missing data from a table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GETEMPLOYEE_INFO
(
P_CPNCOD in varchar2,
P_PAYDAT in date,
P_PAYTYP in varchar2,
P_ERV out varchar2)
is
R_DI_FILLODINF NUMBER(20);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM DI_ELEMOD)
   LOOP
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO R_DI_FILLODINF
     FROM DI_FILLODINF
     WHERE P_CPNCOD=i.CPNCOD and
           P_PAYDAT=i.PAYDAT and
           P_PAYTYP=i.PAYTYP ;

    if nvl(R_DI_FILLODINF,0)<=0
     then   
    dbms_output.put_line ('missing data : ' ||     i.CPNCOD  ||     i.PAYDAT  ||     i.PAYTYP   );
    end if;
    end loop;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
 end;
/
```

but now my problem is, if I put date '01-JUN-12' than output should display missing data but only of year 2012. Please help in this

Thanks alot in advance

```
DECLARE
V_INSTY DI_FILLODINF.INSTYP%TYPE;
BEGIN
GETEMPLOYEE_INFO ('CO','01-JUN-12','D',V_INSTY);
END;
/
```

Comment: Something is strange in your logic- in the "where clause" of your inner query you compare the function params with the values of the outer query (the cursor) and not the columns of `DI_FILLODINF` table, WHY ?

Comment: Hooijdonk i am trying to match the data of table  DI_FILLODINF to the table DI_ELEMOD that it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you right, then what you need to do is select in your outer query only the values from the right year:

```
SELECT * FROM DI_ELEMOD
WHERE PAYDAT >= trunc(P_PAYDAT, 'yyyy') 
AND PAYDAT <= trunc(add_months(P_PAYDAT,12),'yyyy')-1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send only year of particular date , you can use crop data using Substring or many more.